# jquery:ajax not firing in document getready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have added jquery in head section and below code are in body section.
Problem is this isn't working.

Even alert is not showing. I am not getting any error in firebug.
I want to execute ajax on page load. I am not sure my approach is good.

Please advise. Below are the js code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){
         alert('Test');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'profile_exec.php',
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: uid,
                    beforeSend: function() { 
                        $("#validation-errors").hide().empty(); 
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                                var applied_counts = data.applied_count;
                        alert(applied_counts);      
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                        alert('Something went to wrong.Please Try again later...');
                    }
                });             
                return false;

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: try $(document)  without quotes.

Comment: The quotes shouldn't matter

Comment: Without context and the error messages you're seeing, it's going to be very difficult to diagnose this issue.  Please provide an [mcve] or this question is off-topic

Comment: are you sure that you are loading jquery in this page? maybe `$` is undefined.

Comment: go to your browser console and type in $('document') in chrome ... its an empty array, because you try to acces a dom element like <document></document> ....

Comment: I tried without quote in document also uid is defined somewhere else.

Comment: jquery is defined i checked that in firebug and i can see the jquery content.

Comment: try also `console.log($('document'))` see if it returns the document object

Comment: Your chunk of code works by itself (if you replace `uid` with `null`).  The issue is not in this code (with or without the quotes around `document`).  It's showing the Alert and the XHR is erroring out correctly.

Comment: if i remove document get ready then it is working.

Comment: i know its not the topic but .. in my chrome browser i do not get the document with console.log($('document'));
http://www.screencast.com/t/tFqdWfUbJnK5

Comment: maybe something is overriding `$`. try this `jQuery(document).ready(function(){alert('test')})`

Comment: @SimonMüller jQuery has a bunch of aliases for `.ready()`, including nothing at all.  Yes, 'document' is not a valid tag name, but jQuery seems to be fine with using it to alias to `.ready()`.  Like everything else in JavaScript, there's a dozen ways to do anything, all of which are "wrong"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see this should work fine:

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
  alert('ready');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
    method: 'GET',
  }).then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

since even the alert is not showing, check your html code. Maybe swap your jQuery with the google CDN served jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have conflict or noConflict somewhere else. Check this out: [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Try this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){alert('test')})
```